# MySQL not using index as expected with a WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.6

I have a table called mytable and I'm trying to optimize a query on it. I generated the index ind5 on it, and it has the nullable int column col_1 in first place. This query has a `WHERE IN` clause, which seems to throw the query optimizer completely off. Here's something that works:

```
explain select status from mytable use index (ind5)
    where col_1 = 10 limit 0,10'

+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | ref  | ind5              | ind5              | 5       | const | 718156 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

So far so good. Now let's try:

```
explain select status from mytable use index (ind5)
    where col_1 in (1, 10)  limit 0,10'

+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | ALL  | ind5              | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1436312 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

What changed here? I'm using a `WHERE IN`, but that should be equivalent to `col_1 = 1 OR col_1 = 10`, so I would still expect MySQL to use the index, which it's clearly not doing. How about if I do:

```
explain select status from mytable use index (ind5)
    where col_1 = 10 or col_1 = 1 limit 0,10'

+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | ALL  | ind5              | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1436312 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Lost me completely here. What happened? Why is MySQL not using ind5?

This is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: It would help to know what `ind5` is.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: #1 MySql 5.6 is a bit old, newer versions might handle it better

Comment: #2 LIMIT should not be used without ORDER BY

Comment: How much of the table matches the values 1 and 10? If it's a large enough portion of the table, the optimizer skips the index because it estimates it'll be less costly to just do the table-scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `col_1` is not the *first* (or only) column in index `ind5`.  Or, many rows have `col_1 = 10`.  Please provide output from

```
SELECT col_1, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY col_1;
```

Meanwhile,

```
INDEX(col_1, status)
```

Is optimal for all three queries.

That `IN` and that `OR` are optimized the same.

Tacking `status` onto the index makes it "covering", hence no need to reach into the data's BTree.

Here's another way to check performance (even if "too few" rows):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Note:  If more than about 20% of the rows have `col_1=10`, the Optimizer will decide to scan the table rather than bouncing back and forth between the Index's BTree and the data's BTree.

Comment: Yes the row count is over 20% of total. Thanks.